# error {"type":"pg-client","timestamp":"2021-08-02T05:04:50.035+0000","level":"warn","detail":{"message":"postgres connection failed, retrying(0)."}}

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, hasura, hasura-docker

I am having some issues getting Hasura to connect to postgres.

The error `error {"type":"pg-client","timestamp":"2021-08-02T05:04:50.035+0000","level":"warn","detail":{"message":"postgres connection failed, retrying(0)."}}`  after using docker-compose up

Here is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis
    container_name: db1
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.0.1
    container_name: hasura1
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
    - "postgres"
    restart: always
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@postgres:5432/postgres
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@postgres:5432/postgres
      ## enable the console served by server
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      ## enable debugging mode. It is recommended to disable this in production
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: "true"
      ## uncomment next line to set an admin secret
      # HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: 
volumes:
  db_data:
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Focal. The docker-compose file works on my mac but not on linux box.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get hasura to work on ubuntu, in case anyone is having an issue, you use network_mode: host and use localhost in the postgres string inside your docker-compose.yml file

Comment: That's a workaround, not a solution. It seems you have issues with your docker configuration